# xaml shapes - relative to canvas size

Tags: xaml, drawing

I have the need to draw shapes in XAML that are always relative to the container window/canvas size.  For example, I need a window to show a 3x3 grid on it, where the grid always splits the window into 3 equal parts.  Can I create lines that are bound to 1/3 the width of the grid?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ColumnDefinitions in XAML, for the grid that you want ... all you need to do is set the Column's width to a percentage and you'll get the desired affect.

You can then set border's to create the lines you're looking for.

Does that solve your problem, or am I missing something

Comment: this should work, but I was using a canvas instead of a grid, because I'll be rendering shapes are arbitrary points in the next phase of the project.

Comment: you can still use canvas ... you'll just need to position the elements through more logic and probably in code.